# Error MSB4186: Invalid sta tic method invocation syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, visual-studio, mediasoup

I am trying to setup MediaSoup on one of my NodeJS projects. In my PC I have Visual Studio 2019 Community version running, I followed the instructions as described in the MediaSoup documentation, but I keep getting this error when trying to install MediaSoup from my terminal:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.props(29,5): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::FindRootFolderWhereAllFilesExist($(_VCTargetsPathFolders), $(_RelativeToolsetFiles))". Method 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper.FindRootFolderWhereAllFilesExist' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).  [C:\Projects\NodeJS\CribMd\CribMd-Api\node_modules\mediasoup\worker\deps\getopt\getopt.vcxproj]

What am I doing wrong?